# Question Appeal

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585844/how-do-karma-jasmine-and-protractorangularjs-relate?noredirect=1#comment34432682_22585844

I don't think this question is about opinions but It was closed as so. I don't think the moderator understood the services in depth enough to realize why they were confusing.

EDIT:

[Why is Stack Overflow - and Stack Exchange in general - so scary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/why-is-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-so-scary/202170#202170)

Sigh, I guess this is a common issue and gripe with the community. I feel like a kid getting upset over something like let's say being robbed or lied to even though it's an issue people have been upset with for years. I guess this is just the way SO is. It's a community of diverse people and sub-communities that you can't treat as one. Some people ignore bad questions, some people try to ask the best they can, and some see themselves as guardians protecting the purity of their ideal. It just is what it is.

Comment: If it's not opinion based, then it is definitely too broad.

Comment: Many blog posts explain these things together. If I knew how to break down the question I wouldn't need to ask any question at all. How would you ask the question or how would you break it down? Where in SO would you ask "I don't know how to break this down?" questions? Think of replies as google-map-search snapshots. I think you should be able to ask for snapshots of any zoom level while I fell that others believe that these snapshots should always be of the maximum zoom level.

Comment: @user2483724 Some questions just don't have a place on SO at all, and can't be just repharsed.  SO is not a good "starting place" for some topic.  It's not a tutorial site.  It sounds like this issue is just too broad for SO.  You should be going to other sources, tutorial sites, blogs, etc. to solve this problem.  You can potentially have a question for SO in response to a specific problem that raised from something you saw in one of those resources, but you need to be careful to keep the scope narrow.

Comment: @Servy So there is no place at all in the internet for these types of questions? Because your recommended answer is just to hope that someone has created a blog post explaining? Some of the most popular SO answers are closed as too broad even though there are many likes and favorites. Whether it is intended to be so or not, SO is being used as such a a resource

Comment: @user2483724 You think that just because it's not on topic on SO that there is no place for it on the internet?  That would mean that SO is the entirety of the internet.  Sorry, but it's a *very small* piece of it.  And the fact that some people have asked overly broad questions in the past doesn't mean it's okay for you to do so, as is evidenced by the fact that your question is closed.

Comment: "not on SO" != "no place at all in the internet"

Comment: I'm saying there's currently no good alternative and that SO is the best forum IMO. Please recommended another. Advice of "google and pray that someone's blogged about it" doesn't help. Maybe a spinoff of SO where people request blogs/articles on certain topics that authors could choose to write about based on how popular it is would be useful. If such a thing exists, great! But with my current knowledge of existing platforms, SO is the closest thing to it. I apologize if such a thing exists already and I haven't found it.

Comment: @user2483724 External site recommendations are not on topic on SO (or Meta SO) either.

Comment: @user2483724 Stack Overflow is ***NOT*** a forum. Perhaps this is why you're confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would very much like to know... Why do you think you're being lied to?

Every new user gets links and interstitial pages that should have pointed to these resources:

[What kinds of questions can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
[How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

The nature of your specific question is discussed in detail at [Gorilla Vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Is there something about these resources that is unclear?  Could we improve them, so that new users better understand them?

I've changed the close reason on your question to "Too Broad," since it seems to be a better fit.  Maybe this will alleviate some of the confusion.

Comment: For the same reason people don't read through EULAs. That's an extreme example and I agree that I'm technically wrong here but I believe from a user perspective I have a valid point. (Users want to avoid large overhead) I believe there is HUGE value in connecting people to links rather than just closing those questions. (what google does) Maybe when a question is closed it can have those links you posted. The issue here is emotional not technical. People spend time writing out questions after and I feel it was closed arbitrarily and then directed to pages of documentation as compromise.

Comment: BTW, loved the gorilla/shark article but my original question though on the surface looks like a gorilla vs shark question it is not. It is more like "I'm seeing A vs B a lot, are they both animals or plants?" Or more concretely like someone asking "How do I use NodeJS and Javascript together, they often seem to be used together but I'm not sure what is what, which one is better?" A good answer would untangle this question even though technically it has no right answer. However, by asking the question this way, the asker has managed to succinctly express his confusion.

Comment: Well, thanks for being honest, but failing to read the site instructions isn't really our problem.  Failing to read EULA's doesn't mean that you don't agree to their terms.  You take a risk either way.

Comment: But aren't some startups today providing solutions where EULAs are being simplified so that people actually understand the risk they're taking? (especially w/ the privacy concerns of today) That is a real problem that companies are trying to solve. I feel that you want to improve the UX of SO and I'm pointing out this parallel. It's easier for SO since there aren't any legal issues to dodge around, just some empathy is required.

Comment: That was my question.  Beyond the interstitial pages and the links that we provide new users, how do you suggest that we restructure the materials so that folks like you will actually read them?  I doubt that they could be simplified any further.

Comment: One way is for moderators to stop spreading negative feelings and being combatative when such questions occur. To draw another parallel, if the question is "How do we lower crime rates in bad neighborhoods" the answer would be "Reduce police brutality in these neighborhoods so that the authority is respected rather than seen as the enemy." When a moderator seemingly arbitrarily closes a question with NO EXPLANATION beyond a cookie-cutter template and then says "it's in the rules, if you have an issue, go to court." that prompts people to be angry rather than self-examine.

Comment: @user2483724 I'm not sure how I was combative. If you could let me know what part of my comments were combative, that would help me better structure them so that they aren't taken as combative.  As far as closing the question with "No explanation", I feel like I left a detailed explanation when you asked. Normally I'd leave an explanation *when I close the question* in addition to the text that already accompanies the closure, but in this case I was on my iPhone, and the ability to write a comment is really tough in iOS 7. That damned Enter key is too close to the spacebar (as is the `.`).

Comment: @Geroge Stocker Oh sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you were combative. I was referring to the original moderator who closed my original question. I actually thought your replies were very helpful. (which is why I selected it as an answer)

Comment: @user2483724 I am the one who originally closed your question. Unless, of course, you're referring to another question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Oh, my mistake. Regardless of whether we agree on the semantics of the worlds we're using, (combative might be exaggerated) Your actions have caused a lot of pain. I should have followed my instincts in NOT posting to meta. The actual problem about the original post is lost. If the question were not closed nothing would have happened. I project the root of the problem to have been you and you disagree in that you were just doing the right thing. That is all.

Comment: If you were trying to close a bad question, you've succeeded. If you've hoped to make me enjoy the community more you've failed. Since I could potentially ask limitless idiotic questions out of spite if I were that type of person, your method(or the method in general) may solve the problem in the short term but causes more problems in the long term. Tell someone NOT to do something and they'll do it when you're gone, make someone feel wrong about something and you've taught them something. I as of now still feel the original question was valid. The community disagrees. Oh well.