# Disappointed with Stack overflow-specially the working

Tags: discussion, voting, site-recommendation

Recently I asked a question on Stack overflow which is this:
[JSP with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240406/use-jsp-with-html)

As soon as I could post it, I was rewarded with -4(-2) votes.As a beginner in my Technology, it should be OK to ask a question, which is obviously not off-topic or it violates some Code of conduct.Some kind soul then voted positive for that.

I am also an expert in Microsoft community and see people asking very basic questions and no such system doesn't exist there where asking noob type questions would make your thread deleted.
An MVP of Microsoft states:
*There are no dumb questions, just the people who do not ask them.*

In my opinion this negative system should be abolished and genuine abuses should be handled differently.

Not a complaint, but people seem to be rude here.

Sumit

Comment: The problem is that downvotes are taken damn personal. How else do you suggest we keep up the quality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow - and Stack Exchange in general - so scary?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/why-is-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-so-scary)

Comment: To preempt what's coming next - voting on meta sites is different, if you see downvotes here it probably means people disagree with your premise

Comment: Downvoting is quality control, not rudeness. So, why do _you_ come to stack overflow instead of, say, yahoo answers?

Comment: Two down votes on that question, a couple of users that ask for clarification, one commenter offers a solution and you have two answers. Where is the rudeness? Oh, you failed to add maybe how your code doesn't work, what changes you made to go from a servlet to a jsp page. That is unclear, and a reason for down votes as your question would probably not helpful in that case for future visitors, which is the whole point of Stack Overflow: being useful for future visitors. (yes, that rules out you as the Original Poster).

Comment: A forum shouldn't be driven by a quality control.I agree that OT threads should be deleted, but AFAIK if I had got -5 in my thread it would have been deleted.What was wrong in my thread that I got -4 there.I just want to know this.

Comment: The [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) might be helpful.  And read [How to write a good title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648)

Comment: rene, that got to 4 once, then some one upvoted on that.

Comment: We are not a forum... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Comment: SO isn't a forum, so what should or shouldn't happen in a forum is largely irrelevant

Comment: If you want to know why your SO question got down votes and how you could/should improve your question, you have to ask that on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) but don't come there calling out it's users for being rude because I'm not.

Comment: @sumit Learning a new culture takes time. SO network is not another discussion forum. It's strictly for professional Q&As. Try not to feel upset about the down votes you get, instead you should take them as corrective measures to bring you to the right track gradually.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Answer (score 9):

There's no rules against beginner content on Stack Overflow, there's simply an expectation to follow on-topic rules.

Your post was downvoted (and closed) because it was unclear what you were asking.

You can't just say "*here's my code. it doesn't work. why?*"
There's an expectation to provide relevant information on your what your code will do, what it won't do, and what it should do. As part of the on-topic rules that every Stack Exchange site has, including the ones you violated by posting this question as you did here, on Meta Stack Exchange.

Downvotes aren't personal insults or jabs at you, they're simply a way, like Jan Dvorak says, of judging quality in posts.

Downvotes are open game, there's no rules against what you can and can't downvote, so if people want to downvote you for asking a easy question, then that's their decision, petty as it may be, it's their personal decision.

There's no issue with beginner content, beginner content are the first rungs on the ladder of greatness, and while we don't like it, there are people that will stand at the top of the ladder looking down on those below them. If you don't like it, climb a different ladder, or climb faster.